# Get gateway address in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, ip-address, gateway, berkeley-sockets

I use `ioctl()` to set the gateway address (`SIOCADDRT` with `RTF_GATEWAY` in the flags).

What's the standard ioctl routine to retrieve it?

Comment: What operating system is this? That's probably important to add.

Comment: I am using an array of operating systems, from eCos to uCLinux, passing through Linux and Windows as well. The gateway setting routine is practically identical on all of them, same for getting IP address or mask, they are standard.

Comment: Retreiving the routing table, which is what you're actually going to need to do, unless I'm completely mistaken, is a highly OS-dependent task.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that there is no 'standard ioctl routine' to get the gateway address in a cross-platform-friendly fashion. On Linux you might consider looking at using Netlink sockets, as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288065/getting-gateway-to-use-for-a-given-ip-in-ansi-c).